# Add MXML event listener on component's child

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I'm not sure if this is possble, but I would like to add an event listener on a sub component from MXML. Something like this:

**My Component**

```
<s:Group>
    <s:Button id="myBtn" label="click me" />
</s:Group>
```

**Main Application**

```
<local:MyComponent>
    <local:myBtn click="doSomething()" />
</local:MyComponent>
```

I know that I can do this in code, I just want to know if it's possible to do this in MXML. If it's possible, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but requires a lot of setup.

First add event metadata to MyComponent:

```
<s:Group>
  <fx:Metadata>
        [Event(name="click", type="flash.events.MouseEvent")]
  </fx:Metadata>
    <s:Button id="myBtn" label="click me" />
</s:Group>
```

In theory you should make sure that your component also dispatches the click event; however since click will bubble by default you do not need to do anything else for that event.

Now, your main component will show the event in MXML code hinting, and the compiler will not complain:

```
<local:MyComponent click="doSomething()>
</local:MyComponent>
```

Generally, I would not recommend trying to drill down into a component in order to place listeners on events dispatched by a component's children. It is a break of encapsulation.  The parent component should not know implementation details of the children.

Comment: My problem was that I had a component with lots of buttons, I wanted to know which button was pressed. I used your bubbling solution and then `switch(event.target)` to check the button

Comment: That will work; but in that case; I would have recommended that each button dispatch their own custom event type.  This way your parent is interacting with a set of APIs defined by the child; as opposed to "knowing" specifics about the child.

Comment: I know what you mean, and I've done it that way before. it's great for encapsulation but it's a lot to manage and set up. Also I don't think there's much difference between knowing which events a component dispatches, and which properties/sub-components (buttons) it has.